# Print Record In Descending ORDER using GROUP BY and ORDER BY Clause

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery, sql-order-by

I am new in php. I have a problem i cant get my record in Descending order.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    include ("connection.php");

    $q_opinion="SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as opinion, r.notification_date, t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle, pr.opinion_id, pc.id, pr.client_id as pr_client, pc.address, pc.liaison_one, city.id, pc.head_office_id, city.city, pc.title as cname
        FROM og_ratings r 
        LEFT JOIN og_companies c
        ON r.client_id = c.id
        LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
        ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
        LEFT JOIN og_actions a
        ON r.pacra_action = a.id
        LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
        ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
        LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
        ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
        LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
        ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
        LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr
        ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
        LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc
        ON pc.id = pr.client_id
        LEFT JOIN city
        ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
        WHERE r.client_id  IN (SELECT opinion_id FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations WHERE client_id = 50)
Group By r.client_id
ORDER BY r.client_id DESC
    ";
    $result = mysql_query($q_opinion) or die;
    $rating = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $id[] = $row['client_id'];
        $action[] = $row['atitle'];
        $opinion[] = $row['opinion'];
    }
    for ($i=0; $i<count($rating); $i++)
    {
        if ($rating[$i] == "")continue;
        ?>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $id[$i] ?> </td>
                    <td><?= $opinion[$i] ?> </td>
                    <td><?= $action[$i] ?> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    <?php   
    }
?>
```

**Now I explain my code and my problem**

I have multiple tables and I joined them using left join. 
First of all I'll explain my sub-query. This query contain multiple results of id:

[image]

After that i have a table `og_ratings` in which i have record against that `id's`

[image]

In `og_ratings` table the column `client_id` is used as a foreign key of `opinion_id`

**My Code is working well But i have problem in Descending order**

When i run this code my descending order clause is only working on `id` not on data

**My code output is**
[image]

Here it only working of my variable `$id` and `$opinion` it not working on `$action`. I want to apply descending order on `$action`.

I hope you can understand my question. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I did it by following code

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
$q_opinion="SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as opinion, r.notification_date, t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle, pr.opinion_id, pc.id, pr.client_id as pr_client, pc.address, pc.liaison_one, city.id, pc.head_office_id, city.city, pc.title as cname
FROM og_ratings r 
    inner join
(
  select max(notification_date) notification_date,
    client_id
  from og_ratings
  group by client_id
  ORDER BY notification_date DESC
) r2
  on r.notification_date = r2.notification_date
  and r.client_id = r2.client_id
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr
ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc
ON pc.id = pr.client_id
LEFT JOIN city
ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
WHERE r.client_id  IN (SELECT opinion_id FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations WHERE client_id = 50)";
$result = mysql_query($q_opinion) or die;
$rating = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $rating[] = $row['client_id'];
  $action[] = $row['atitle'];
  $opinion[] = $row['opinion'];
  $date[] = $row['notification_date'];
  $lrating[] = $row['ltitle'];
  $srating[] = $row['stitle'];
}
for ($i=0; $i<count($rating); $i++) {
    if ($rating[$i] == "")continue;
     ?>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
          <td><?= $rating[$i] ?> </td>
           <td><?= $date[$i] ?> </td>
          <td><?= $opinion[$i] ?> </td>
         <td><?= $action[$i] ?> </td>
          <td><?= $lrating[$i] ?> </td>
           <td><?= $srating[$i] ?> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php   
}
?>
```